# custom sortfunction that are case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat where I the orderBy-function. I've noticed that it's not working as I would like it to do when it comes to case sensitivity

In my example you see that "BBBBB" comes before "aaaaa", which is wrong in my case. "aaaaa" should be ordered before "BBBBB".

I'm not sure how to do this..Can anyone help me?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ICNuVCkotSaIsfvdQGTt?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example - example-example105-production</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="orderByExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table class="friend">

<tr>
  <th>
     <button ng-click="order('group')">Name</button>
     <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'group'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
 </th>
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
  <td>{{friend.group}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('orderByExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', [
            '$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.friends = [
                   { group: ['aaaaa'] },
                   { group: ['BBBBB'] },
                   { group: ['AAAA'] },
                ];
                $scope.predicate = 'group';
                $scope.reverse = false;
                $scope.order = function (predicate) {
                    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                    $scope.predicate = 'group';
                };
            }
        ]);
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your predicate to a function:

```
$scope.predicate = function(d) { return d.group[0].toLowerCase(); };
```

Comment: But it still changes when re-ordering?

Comment: What do you mean?  You wanted the result to be case insensitive sorting: ["AAAA"]
["aaaaa"]
["BBBBB"]

Comment: Yes, but when you press the "Name" button it changes back

Comment: That was unclear.  Then update both predicates.  http://plnkr.co/edit/zGNlhRWRNlFlCkpavJZC?p=preview

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I believe it's still wrong because the order function is not working, when reverse the order should "BBBBB" come first

Comment: Are you looking for the button to toggle direction?  Then you need to update that function.  It has nothing to do with case insensitivity.  http://plnkr.co/edit/zGNlhRWRNlFlCkpavJZC?p=preview

Comment: So sorry I quite new to this..But your last plunkr did the trick. Thank you

Comment: There is one thing I dont understand here..the function takes a parameter (d) but when calling it by "orderBy|predicate" I never send any parameters..how does that work?

Comment: Read the API documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy  The first parameter to orderBy is expression which an be either a function(*), string or array of such (in cases where the primary key is not-unique and you need to dive further to uniquely sequence).  The function is a 'Getter' which means you get one element to provide the key that will be applied to <, === or >.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't actually the case.  It's due to the fact that your data is not comprised of strings.  Change the data structure to be like so:

```
$scope.friends =
    [{group:'aaaaa'},
    {group:'BBBBB'},
    {group:'AAAA'},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your predicate as

```
   $scope.predicate = function(item) {
     return item.group.join('').toUpperCase();
  };
```